# how to add autocomplete function to a column in oracle apex tabular form report

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

i want to add an autocomplete function to work in one of my column suppose name.It is easy to do using items.but how can i do it in the report.

Comment: Waiting for some response

Comment: Have a look https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=46011:20:14503604802631::NO:::

Comment: hi pranav i dnt have much knowledge in js so i/t is hard fr me to understand the steps. can u help me out of this

Answer (score 0):

Since a report doesn't contain Apex items, you can't do this with the built in features. Ignoring any possible plugins that may already be available, you can do this with jQuery UI, specifically the [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget. Apex already includes some of the jQuery UI suite, but you may need to download the Autocomplete widget from the jQuery website.

This will need some custom work on your end. This really isn't that hard if you know how to use jQuery.

1. Download the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget and include it on your page. You can put just the .js file for that in your Application Shared Items. I have the whole jQuery UI library in a separate place on the webserver because I use different parts for different projects.
2. Source in that widget in the page properties.
3. You'll need to create text items with `apex_item.text` in your report.
4. You'll need an On Page Load dynamic action to attach the Autocomplete widget to your text items.
5. For the autocomplete source, if it's short, you can just use a Javascript variable that you put on the Apex page. If it's longer or you need to find the list at run time, you can use a function that calls apex.server.process.
6. If your report has Partial Page Refresh turned on, make sure the DA in step 4 has Dynamic scope, not Static.

Comment: thanks for the responce but is their any other way because i dont want to use any item in my report page as u said in step 3.I have normal tabular form report and i just want to do the change in one of the column.